# Codec for ADT do not compile

Tags: mongodb, scala

I'm using the scala driver to make IO operations with mongodb. My scala version is `2.11.11` and the mongo db driver is `2.2.0`.

I take the example in documentation about ADT :

```
sealed class Tree
case class Branch(b1: Tree, b2: Tree, value: Int) extends Tree
case class Leaf(value: Int) extends Tree

val codecRegistry = fromRegistries( fromProviders(classOf[Tree]), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY )
```

This code didn't compile.

```
No known subclasses of the sealed class
[error]     val codecRegistry = fromRegistries( fromProviders(classOf[Tree]), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY )
[error]                                                              ^
[error] knownDirectSubclasses of Tree observed before subclass Branch registered
[error] knownDirectSubclasses of Tree observed before subclass Leaf registered
```

Did I miss something ?

### Update

Below a complete example of what I'm tring to do.

`build.sbt`

```
name := "mongodb-driver-test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "2.2.0"
```

file `Models.scala`

```
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.{DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY, Macros}
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.{fromProviders, fromRegistries}

/**
  * Created by alifirat on 02/01/18.
  */


object Models {

  sealed class Tree
  case class Branch(b1: Tree, b2: Tree, value: Int) extends Tree
  case class Leaf(value: Int) extends Tree

  val treeCodec = Macros.createCodecProvider[Tree]()

  val treeCodecRegistry = fromRegistries( fromProviders(treeCodec), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY )

}
```

Then, just do :

`sbt compile`

You will get :

```
[error]   val treeCodec = Macros.createCodecProvider[Tree]()
[error]                                                   ^
[error] knownDirectSubclasses of Tree observed before subclass Branch registered
[error] knownDirectSubclasses of Tree observed before subclass Leaf registered
[error] three errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

If I change the scala version to `2.12.0`, I didn't have any errors at compile time ...

Comment: Interestingly, I don't see second errors (about "knownDirectSubclasses") but for the "No known subclasses of the sealed class" error for me it requires Scala 2.11 (not 2.12) and putting `Tree`, `Branch` and `Leaf` inside some `object` rather than leaving them on the top level. See this think you should create a full-blown self-contained [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that everyone could try and easily reproduce the issue the same way you see it.

Comment: I just updated my post.

Comment: Same problem to me, scala 2.12, driver version 2.2.0. Remove 'sealed' modifier and it would work. I have no idea why, joined this circus a day ago

Answer (score 3):

I'm using driver version 2.6.0 and Scala version 2.12.8 and still get the same problem.

My workaround is to remove the keyword `sealed` in front of that sealed class, compile, put it back, and then compile again. But it's very cumbersome.

Comment: Are you asking a question or are you providing an answer? Questions should not be asked in answers, instead write a new question. If you are trying to give an answer then please delete the first paragraph. The [help] pages explain the rules for questions and answers on this site. Please review them.

Comment: Is it ok to create a duplicate thread for the same problem? I don't know whether it's a better idea. I'm willing to create a new thread if duplication is allowed.

Comment: Writing another copy of the same question is not allowed, such a duplicate is likely to be closed (as a duplicate). Your answer now appears to be OK to me, it states the software version numbers and it gives a workaround for the problem.If you had more reputation on this site then you could offer a bounty on the question and that might provoke more interest and more answers.

Comment: I suspect that this question and your answer are in a niche topic where few people work, I do not know the topic at all. Searching and asking in other web sites may be your best plan. If you do get a good answer then please come back and update your answer here.

Comment: It's kind of sad that this is only website that I know where to look for programming answer.